# I'm trying to provide limited access to certain functionality using links, bash scripts and SUID. SUID script does not run with root access

Tags: linux, permissions, suid

EDIT: this [Sticky bit enabled Script can't write to a root file](https://serverfault.com/questions/993722/sticky-bit-enabled-script-cant-write-to-a-root-file) appears to be a similar problem

EDIT: [How can I use SetUID on a shell script to run as a non-root user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/397969/how-can-i-use-setuid-on-a-shell-script-to-run-as-a-non-root-user?rq=1) is very similar as well.

I have a script, let's call it read.sh. I have a file, lets call it secret.

```
# cd /home/normie
# echo "some stuff" > secret
# echo "#!/bin/bash" > read.sh
# echo "cat secret" >> read.sh
# chmod 600 secret
# chmod 4755 read.sh
# su normie
$ ./read.sh
<<Error about not having access to secret>>
```

Did I miss something? I thought the SUID bit made the script run as the owner?
When I run the following

```
# echo "touch newfile" > sumfile.sh
# chmod 4755 sumfile.sh
# su normie
$ ./sumfile.sh
$ ls -alh
<<newfile shows as owned by root>>
```

What is going on here, and how do I make it work the way I want?
The way I want being, I want regular users to execute a particular script with full root access. (I thought that's what the suid bit did )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use SetUID on a shell script to run as a non-root user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/397969/how-can-i-use-setuid-on-a-shell-script-to-run-as-a-non-root-user)

Comment: @vidarlo, mostly. I grabbed some info from other places.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install sudo `apt install sudo`

Make the relevant users part of some group `groupadd group && usermod -g group user`

Add the following to /etc/sudoers `%group (ALL)=(root:root) NOPASSWD:/path/to/script.sh`

Add an alias to .bashrc `alias ALIAS='sudo /path/to/script.sh'" >> ~user/.bashrc`

All members of group can now run the script in question as root.

Answer shamelessly stolen from [How can I use SetUID on a shell script to run as a non-root user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/397969/how-can-i-use-setuid-on-a-shell-script-to-run-as-a-non-root-user?rq=1) (user9517)

Comment: Please don't copy answers from Serverfault; rather flag the question as duplicate if you believe another answer can close this question. While the license permits you to copy, it's better to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @CommunityBot
There's a pattern here of the community ignoring my questions until I answer then myself, then rushing in to down vote me, or providing some meaningless prattle that offers no practical advice, and then circle-jerking each other. Until the community starts delivering some actual value, I really don't care what you think of how I answer my own questions.